# Play: Debug message still there even if error level set to ERROR

Tags: playframework, logback

This is my log file of my Play application:

```
  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- Daily rollover with compression -->
        <fileNamePattern>application-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
      </rollingPolicy>
      <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ACCESS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/access.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover with compression -->
      <fileNamePattern>access-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- keep 1 week worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n</pattern>
      <!-- this quadruples logging throughput -->
      <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- additivity=false ensures access log data only goes to the access log -->
  <logger name="access" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="play" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="akka" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Even I set the error level to ERROR, I still get debug messages like this:

```
2015-10-20 02:05:07 -0400 - [DEBUG] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-25
my debug message
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have anything in your application.conf file? It is possible to override the level there e.g. `logger.application=DEBUG`

Comment: No, I removed all the logging stuff from my `application.conf`.